# CKEditor. How to distinguish window.getSelection() when cursor is at the start position and there is no selection

Tags: ckeditor

Currently I am working on the task where it is needed:

- to add special button to the CKEditor toolbar
- this button should open dialog
- dialog window is custom we don`t use default config but this.

  CKEDITOR.plugins.add('addTextButton', {
  // ...
  editor.addCommand(
      'textBlockDialog',
      new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('addTextDialog', {
          allowedContent: true
      })
  );
  editor.ui.addButton('addTextButton', {
     // ...

we can select some text from the dialog window and paste it into CKEditor on the place of cursor

I decided to implemente this functionality in this way:
-firstly I catch beforeDestroy event
-then I am taking the position of cursor by window.getSelection()

```
ckeditorInstance.on('beforeDestroy', event => {
        this.ngModel = event.editor.getData();

        this.start = event.editor.window.$.getSelection();

        this.cursorPosition = event.editor.window.$.getSelection().anchorOffset;

        const range = this.start.getRangeAt(0);

        if (this.start.anchorOffset !== 0) {
            range.insertNode(document.createTextNode('node'));
        }


        if (this.start.anchorOffset === 0) {
            // there I have to add condition whether it is the start 
            position of cursor or there wasn`t selection at all
        }
```

The question is: 
If is it possible to find whether it is the start position of cursor or there wasn`t selection at all.
In all this cases window.getSelection() returns the same object with anchorOffset = 0

Than I have to implement logic for adding text from dialog window to CKEditor
at the start when position of cursor is 0 and at the end when there is no selection.